# ag-grid aggregation for column which has row grouping to be true

Tags: reactjs, angularjs, ag-grid

I have a table as follows
[image]

As you can see in the picture,there is aggregation showing for **Date of Issuance** as `child rows count + transactions`.

Now, if I make **Date of Issuance** column to be `rowGroup:true`, grid is appearing as
[image]

Here the aggregation function which was written to get `child rows count + transactions` isn't working. Is there a way I can still show **aggregation** for a **column** which has `rowGroup: true`